# Tabbing through a textarea that captures tab

Tags: html, text

Many times when I am being tab to switch fields, some times it entered into a text area where pressing tab indent your text. How can I get out these textareas using keyboard so I can continue switching fields.

Comment: Which OS / Browser are you using? Which websites exhibit this behaviour?

Comment: @w3d I don't remember the actual names of sites that do this but here is a fiddle that does the same. http://jsfiddle.net/n6aRj/20/ My broswer is chrome but I think it doesn't depends upon browser

Answer (score 1):

> ...here is a fiddle that does the same.

If the websites themselves are overriding this default/expected behaviour then they are breaking a standard UI feature (and possibly lessening site accessibility - although that may depend on the particular application) and it is really up to the site to implement some kind of alternative. There is no other "built-in" keyboard shortcut to move focus to the "next page element".

If, however, you just want to get focus out of that textarea, then you could perhaps use another shortcut, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> which moves focus to the address bar. From their you can start TABing again to move focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to do what you need:

http://postcode.cf/support-tabs-in-text-areas.html

```
/* Support Tabs within your textarea */

HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype.getCaretPosition = function () { //return the caret position of the textarea
    return this.selectionStart;
};
HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype.setCaretPosition = function (position) { //change the caret position of the textarea
    this.selectionStart = position;
    this.selectionEnd = position;
    this.focus();
};
HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype.hasSelection = function () { //if the textarea has selection then return true
    if (this.selectionStart == this.selectionEnd) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype.getSelectedText = function () { //return the selection text
    return this.value.substring(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd);
};
HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype.setSelection = function (start, end) { //change the selection area of the textarea
    this.selectionStart = start;
    this.selectionEnd = end;
    this.focus();
};

var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]; 

textarea.onkeydown = function(event) {

    //support tab on textarea
    if (event.keyCode == 9) { //tab was pressed
        var newCaretPosition;
        newCaretPosition = textarea.getCaretPosition() + "    ".length;
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, textarea.getCaretPosition()) + "    " + textarea.value.substring(textarea.getCaretPosition(), textarea.value.length);
        textarea.setCaretPosition(newCaretPosition);
        return false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 8){ //backspace
        if (textarea.value.substring(textarea.getCaretPosition() - 4, textarea.getCaretPosition()) == "    ") { //it's a tab space
            var newCaretPosition;
            newCaretPosition = textarea.getCaretPosition() - 3;
            textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, textarea.getCaretPosition() - 3) + textarea.value.substring(textarea.getCaretPosition(), textarea.value.length);
            textarea.setCaretPosition(newCaretPosition);
        }
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 37){ //left arrow
        var newCaretPosition;
        if (textarea.value.substring(textarea.getCaretPosition() - 4, textarea.getCaretPosition()) == "    ") { //it's a tab space
            newCaretPosition = textarea.getCaretPosition() - 3;
            textarea.setCaretPosition(newCaretPosition);
        }    
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39){ //right arrow
        var newCaretPosition;
        if (textarea.value.substring(textarea.getCaretPosition() + 4, textarea.getCaretPosition()) == "    ") { //it's a tab space
            newCaretPosition = textarea.getCaretPosition() + 3;
            textarea.setCaretPosition(newCaretPosition);
        }
    } 
}
```